# How to get a object's value by a key list

Tags: javascript

I have a obj you see bellow:

```
var obj = {
  a: {
    b:{
      c:"c"
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to get value like bellow :

```
var t = ["a", "b", "c"]  // give a key list

console.log(obj["a"]["b"]["c"])  // and get value like this.
```

in depth, I want to encapsulate the requirement in a function:

```
function get_value(obj, key_list) {

}
```

because the `key_list` is not certain, so how to realize the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `while` loop and iterate over the keys

```js
var obj = {
  a: {
    b:{
      c:"c"
    }
  }
}
var t = ["a", "b", "c"];
function get_value(obj, key_list) {
  let currentReference = obj;
  while (key_list.length !== 0) {
    currentReference = currentReference[key_list[0]];
    key_list = key_list.slice(1);
  }
  return currentReference;
}
console.log(get_value(obj, t));
```

It'd be more elegant with `reduce` though:

```js
var obj = {
  a: {
    b:{
      c:"c"
    }
  }
}
var t = ["a", "b", "c"];
function get_value(obj, key_list) {
  return key_list.reduce((currentReference, key) => currentReference[key], obj);
}
console.log(get_value(obj, t));
```

Comment: I presume the order of the keys in the array is important. For example if position of  key `b` & `c` is interchanged that will create issue

Comment: that reduce solution looks pretty

Answer (score 2):

Recursive solution:

```
function get_value(obj, key_list, i) {
  if (i == undefined) {
    i = 0;
  }
  if (i < key_list.length - 1) {
    return get_value(obj[key_list[i]], key_list, i+1)
  }
  return obj[key_list[i]]
}
```